# Not able to scaffold with dotnet ef core on mac

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to use .net core to reverse engineer model classes from existing database on my MAC. The database is running in a VM with windows and I am able to connect to it from osx.

In my project.json I have the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "compile": {
      "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    }
  }
```

But when I run

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "myDbConnectString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I get the following error and I can not get passed this

> ```
>  An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureDesignTimeServices' on startup class
> ```
>
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.SqlServerDesignTimeServices'.
>   Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the
>   DbContext at design-time. Error: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>           System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.IScaffoldingModelFactory'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator'.)
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.IScaffoldingModelFactory'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator'.
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider
>   provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean
>   throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider
>   provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService
>   service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>              at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2
>   dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DatabaseOperations.ReverseEngineerAsync(String
>   provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
>   dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables,
>   Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.OperationExecutor.ReverseEngineerAsync(String
>   provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
>   dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1
>   tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DbContextScaffoldCommand.d__1.MoveNext()
>              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>              at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>              at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[]
>   args)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
>           ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.IScaffoldingModelFactory'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator'.
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider
>   provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean
>   throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider
>   provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService
>   service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type
>   serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>              at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2
>   dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)
>              at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DatabaseOperations.ReverseEngineerAsync(String
>   provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
>   dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables,
>   Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.OperationExecutor.ReverseEngineerAsync(String
>   provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String
>   dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1
>   tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>              at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DbContextScaffoldCommand.d__1.MoveNext()<---
>           One or more errors occurred. (Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.IScaffoldingModelFactory'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator'.)

I have tried to change versions of my dependencies back and forth but with no result. Anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it to work.
I updated to .net core 1.1.0 and modified my project.json to use newer versions. Hope this can help someone else

project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "type": "platform"
  },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
    "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "type": "build"
  },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",

  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0"
},

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an RTM version of Entity Framework?

```js
{
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Not those version but I just got it to work. Will post my new project.json to maybe help someone else